# Where can I find city zoning district in Dallas, Texas data?

Tags: geospatial, uses-of-open-data, city

I need some open data source where I can download zoning areas of Dallas,  Texas. I have tried to find it using official city GIS data, using ArcGIS online but not even close to find that.

Comment: I take it the links from https://dallascityhall.com/departments/sustainabledevelopment/planning/Pages/zoning.aspx are unhelpful?

Comment: I have already found it on Dalas open data portal. I need a shapefiles and I found it.

Comment: @user122678 please post the above comment as an answer.